# How to avoid that music control center "forgets" music app?

Tags: iphone, ios, music, control-center

Music control center works perfectly fine, except it sometimes seems to "forget" the music app I was using it with. And then just clicking wont do it anymore. Instead I have to click at the top and reopen the app first and start the song there. After doing that, I can control it from control center again.

How can this be avoided. In the ideal case, i can always start playing a song from the music control center by just clicking play (without having to reopen the app first). How it looks when I have to reopen the app first, you can see in the second pic.

Please see pictures for better understanding. 
[image]
[image]

Comment: What exactly is your question here?

Comment: clarified my question

Comment: This happens since iOS 10, even with just the default Music app. The situation has vastly improved since iOS 10.2-ish, but still persists. I'm guessing either a bug, or a memory management problem.